# someone cites one case in particular

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

Does **"Deutsche cites one case in particular"** in the following context mean **"Deutsche is only one of them"**?

> Context:
>
> Lefebvre’s ‘slogan’ implies, for my purposes, art that is sited or
>   ‘plays some part’ in the ‘culture’ of the city and that is produced as
>   a response to – and therefore, importantly, contributes to producing
>   in turn – city existence. At the same time I am interested, as I
>   believe I have intimated, in the notion of the city itself as a
>   performing and performative entity or cultural product based on how
>   people and other phenomena act, are seen to act or, indeed, are
>   permitted to act, within it. Of course, these various instances of
>   relationships between art and the city have been the subject of
>   theorisation – to an ever increasing degree and from a range of
>   disciplinary points of view – and they are fraught with
>   ‘difficulties’. Not least I take note of Rosalyn Deutsche’s critique
>   of art history’s ‘several traditional ways’ of categorising this
>   relationship: ‘The city can be a work of art. The city, or the
>   experience of the city, influences the subject matter and form of
>   works of art. And, of course, there are art works situated in the city
>   – public art’. Despite noises by some critics – **Deutsche cites one
>   case in particular** – in the direction of a new public art ‘immersed
>   in, rather than aloof from, metropolitan life’, such delineations
>   always seem to collapse back into assumptions of aesthetic essence
>   and, indeed, transcendence which ‘ignore the city’s social processes
>   and their effects on the everyday life of residents’

Comment: No. To cite - to name, to mention, to quote. Rosalyn Deutsche is a person, not a case...

Comment: @Mr Lister  yes I know the meaning of "to cite". I want to know what  Deutsche cites? Her own idea as a critic on the relationships of art and city, as mentioned in the previous sentence? or the idea of other critics on the subject?

Comment: What she cites is one of these "noises". I'm not sure how to explain better; sorry. (That's why I didn't post as an answer BTW)

Comment: "Despite noises [reviews] by some critics – John cites one case in particular" = "Despite noises [reviews] by some critics – John cites one noise [review] in particular." (***NOTE***: Don't write like whoever wrote that passage.)

Comment: I've read it a few times and find it ambiguous - it could refer to the example of city/art, but she might also reference another critic.  On balance, I think it is more likely to be the former as it would be strange to refer to 'one case' and then not expand further if it was not the one already mentioned, but the only way to know this for sure would be to read Rosalyn Deutsche's work.  And yes, I think it implies that Deutsche is only one of them, though she herself is citing a critic in her own work.

Answer (score 2):

The one "case in particular" refers to a critical review (referred to as "noise") she (Deautsche) cited. The cited critical review advocated a public art "immersed in, rather than aloof from, metropolitan life."

What is confusing is that the author of this piece is critiquing the author of another piece critiquing the author of another piece who is critiquing attitudes toward public art. A meta-meta-critique.

Also, academic writing in English is notorious for having horrible prose, and ironically the worst writing is found in the humanities. This piece is a model of bad, unclear writing. Though I'm a native speaker I had to reread it several times.

Thank you for reminding me why I decided not to major in the humanities back in university.